# angular using explicit notation failing at app.config()

Tags: angularjs

So I've been trying to minify my code, and it's not been an easy journey.

Everything works if nothing is minified or bundled. The first thing I was told to do is not to minify first, and add "ng-strict-di" to the ng-app element. So that when I take care of all the errors that throw, I can minify no problem.

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
```

And I refreshed the page, and then I got my error.

```
JavaScript error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate
module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:strictdi] function(toastrConfig) is not using explicit
annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
```

This is the library I'm using: https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr

In the documentation it shows how to apply a global configuration to all my toastrs:

```
app.config(function(toastrConfig) {
  angular.extend(toastrConfig, {
    allowHtml: false,
    closeButton: false,
    closeHtml: '<button>&times;</button>',
    extendedTimeOut: 1000,
    iconClasses: {
      error: 'toast-error',
      info: 'toast-info',
      success: 'toast-success',
      warning: 'toast-warning'
    },  
    messageClass: 'toast-message',
    onHidden: null,
    onShown: null,
    onTap: null,
    progressBar: false,
    tapToDismiss: true,
    templates: {
      toast: 'directives/toast/toast.html',
      progressbar: 'directives/progressbar/progressbar.html'
    },
    timeOut: 5000,
    titleClass: 'toast-title',
    toastClass: 'toast'
  });
});
```

Again everything works if I remove ng-strict-di, but when I apply it.. it errors out. If I remove the app.config code, everything works.. but I need this as I have a lot of toastr notifications throughout my app. So what's going on here? I couldn't find anything related to this in the angular docs, and it shows that I'm using app.config correctly, so why is this being a problem?

Comment: [I found this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi) just googling a phrase in your error that stood out to me.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors on my controllers, I'm getting an error on app.config part. I'm using controllers correctly according to that link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going through the link that I commented, and after some double checking, I *believe* (never had to use this) that your problem is that you are requiring angular to implicitly figure out which providers you want. In strict mode (which was in that link I sent you), you have to *explicitly* define them. Here is an example from the Angular docs.

```
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);
```

Notice the array syntax.

So for you, try

```
app.config(['toastrConfig',function(toastrConfig) {
  angular.extend(toastrConfig, {
    allowHtml: false,
    closeButton: false,
    closeHtml: '<button>&times;</button>',
    extendedTimeOut: 1000,
    iconClasses: {
      error: 'toast-error',
      info: 'toast-info',
      success: 'toast-success',
      warning: 'toast-warning'
    },  
    messageClass: 'toast-message',
    onHidden: null,
    onShown: null,
    onTap: null,
    progressBar: false,
    tapToDismiss: true,
    templates: {
      toast: 'directives/toast/toast.html',
      progressbar: 'directives/progressbar/progressbar.html'
    },
    timeOut: 5000,
    titleClass: 'toast-title',
    toastClass: 'toast'
  });
}]);
```

Comment: yes: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:strictdi] function(toastrConfig) is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode

Comment: I'm thinking it might have to do with the library that I'm using. It works without the strict-di .. but if I can't get this to work, I can't minify my files.

Comment: does it give you a file name/line?

Comment: [I've got this very rudimentary plunkr going](https://plnkr.co/edit/BWaRlFYAv3jQrKJPHtWG?p=preview) and everything seems fine.

Comment: AHHH I just found out my javascript wasn't being updated! So weird. Some javascript files for different pages get updated when I change it, but for the one I was on, it wasn't. This worked thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `'toastrConfig'` in the `.config` and `.extend`

```
app.config(['toastrConfig',function(toastrConfig) {
  angular.extend(['toastrConfig', toastrConfig, {
    allowHtml: false,
    closeButton: false,
    closeHtml: '<button>&times;</button>',
    extendedTimeOut: 1000,
    iconClasses: {
      error: 'toast-error',
      info: 'toast-info',
      success: 'toast-success',
      warning: 'toast-warning'
    },  
    messageClass: 'toast-message',
    onHidden: null,
    onShown: null,
    onTap: null,
    progressBar: false,
    tapToDismiss: true,
    templates: {
      toast: 'directives/toast/toast.html',
      progressbar: 'directives/progressbar/progressbar.html'
    },
    timeOut: 5000,
    titleClass: 'toast-title',
    toastClass: 'toast'
  }]);
}]);
```

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di